# XML-parsing unable to find characters - swift

Tags: xml, swift, parsing

I'm having an issue parsing some XML-code in swift.

The parsing works well except for one element in the XML-file:

```
<media:thumbnail width="2048" height="1152" url="www..." />
```

In exception to the other elements that are successfully parsed, note that it is a self-closing element.

I use four functions to parse the file:

```
// 1
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

    switch elementName {
    case "title": entry.title = String()
    case "description": entry.desc = String()
    case "media:thumbnail": entry.media = String()
    case "link": entry.link = String()
    case "pubDate": entry.pubDate = String()
    default: break
    }
    currentParsedElement = elementName

}

// 2
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    switch currentParsedElement {
    case "title": entry.title = entry.title + string
    case "description": entry.desc = entry.desc + string
    case "media:thumbnail": entry.media = entry.media + string
    case "link": entry.link = entry.link + string
    case "pubDate": entry.pubDate = entry.pubDate + string
    default: break
    }


}

// 3
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    if elementName == "title" || elementName == "description" || elementName == "link" || elementName == "pubDate" || elementName == "media:thumbnail" {
        currentParsedElement = ""
    }

    if elementName == "item" {
        entriesArray.append(entry);
        entry = Entry()
    }

}

// 4
func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {

    reloadTableView()

}
```

I've tested the code and it seems that it successfully finds the element in the first function. However, instantly after, it runs the third function which ends the element.

Thus, it seems like the parser recognizes any character in the element as a call to end the parsing of that element.

Comment: This is exactly as expected since the element has no content whatsoever. You can find the attributes and their values in the `attributeDict` argument of the first function

Comment: THANK YOU! That's great! :)